# マルチSNS対応のシェアボタンのライブラリを探しています

Tags: javascript, html, html5

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Facebook、Twitter、Lineに対応したシェアボタンのライブラリを探しています。
ライブラリを一つ追加することで、それぞれのボタンをクリックしたら記事のURLを取得して、それぞれのサービスに渡せるようになるのが希望です。

#### 試したこと

Facebook、Twitterに対応したライブラリは確認できたのですが、LINEに対応したものがなかったです。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、回答よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/88805

Answer (score 0):

https://media.line.me/ja/how_to_install
この方法でどうでしょうか？LINEなら使ってるサイト多そうなので有名サイトを探せばあるんじゃないでしょうか？